# Just installed Arduino 2.0.3 - what is windows path to associated libraries?

Tags: arduino-ide, library, arduino-ide-2

Just installed Arduino 2.0.3 and I attempted to build a sketch which includes a library that I manually installed in version 1.8.19 and it can't be found:

In my program I have
`#include <DS3231.h>`

Now, attempting to compile it cannot find the library.

What is the path to the basic libraries in Arduino 2.0.3?

Comment: as in IDE1, it is the `libraries` folder in the sketchbook folder. the location of the sketchbook folder is in the Preferences dialog in the IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the location by examining the app while it was running.

The associated libraries are at:

`%localappdata%\arduino15\Libraries`

That will look like : `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Arduino15\libraries`

I created a new folder named `DS3231` dropped in the .cpp, .h and .config files and now my sketch compiles with the `#include <DS3231.h>`

Kind of blows my mind that the Arduino 2.0.3 Libraries are found in a directory named Arduino15.  Is that an old version or something?

Here's what I see in preferences -- don't see a location for user libraries:

[image: arduino preferences]

The best location will be your sketchbook location + a folder named `libraries`.

For example, in my case my sketchbook location is :

`c:\users\<username>\dev\arduino`

so my library folder should be:

`c:\users\<username>\dev\arduino\libraries`

Comment: *"in a directory named Arduino15. Is that an old version or something?"* The `15` comes from the the **1.5**.x series IDE which first introduced support for boards other than the original set of AVR boards, was carried into arduino-builder, and arduino-cli were it remains relevant to current day IDEs. It is *not* a normal place to add user libraries.

Comment: @timemage Where would the place be to add user libraries?  I've added an image to the answer showing the Arduino 2.0.3 preferences but I don't see any location that would work.  Do you have an alternative path in mind that works for 2.0.3?  Thanks

Comment: do you see the location of the sketchbook folder in the Preferences dialog? then read my comment again and slow